# Why ndimage.label(image) labels extra shapes among the considered ones?  

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

When I use `ndimage.label(img)` imported from `scipy` package to label a gray scale PNG image it behaves like this.
I have two images with some shapes made by `Photoshop`:
The first image :
[the test_one http://imageshack.us/a/img140/8669/onehx.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img140/8669/onehx.png)
I perform this code on the above image.

```
>>> from scipy.misc import imread
>>> from scipy.ndimage import (label,find_objects)

>>> img=imread('first.jpg')
>>> x,y = label(img)
>>> print y                 # Prints exactly "4" shapes ,which is right.
4

>>> f=find_objects(x)
>>> print f                 # Returns exactly the "4" slices of the considered shapes.
[(slice(16L, 61L, None), slice(149L, 189L, None)),  
(slice(30L, 40L, None), slice(60L, 90L, None)),  
(slice(50L, 70L, None), slice(20L, 120L, None)),  
(slice(96L, 149L, None), slice(130L, 186L, None))]
```

Till now,it works fine.
But when I make a shape with a smooth brush like shown in here:

The second image:
[the test_one http://imageshack.us/a/img822/5696/twozg.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img822/5696/twozg.png)
I perform this code on the second image

```
>>> from scipy.misc import imread
>>> from scipy.ndimage import (label,find_objects)

>>> img=imread('second.jpg')
>>> x,y = label(img)
>>>print y               # Prints more than "5" shapes ,which is wrong.
6

>>> f=find_objects(x)
>>> print f               # Return more than the "5" slices of the considered shapes.
                          #But still has the "5" slices of the "5" considered shapes 
                          #among the other slices which I'm confused of.  
[(slice(16L, 61L, None), slice(149L, 189L, None)),  
(slice(30L, 40L, None), slice(60L, 90L, None)),  
(slice(50L, 70L, None), slice(20L, 120L, None)),  
(slice(96L, 149L, None), slice(130L, 186L, None)),  
(slice(126L, 170L, None), slice(65L, 109L, None)),  
(slice(127L, 128L, None), slice(79L, 80L, None))]    #This is the extra object.
```

I just want to know why `ndimage.label(img)` labeled more than the considered shapes when   I use a smooth brush .
Yes it could label the considered shapes but why the extra labeling and how can I get rid of the extra labeled shapes .

Note:
(1)The extra shapes aren't even shapes ,they are kinda thin black regions.!!
(2)It behaves the same way if the image was in an RGB format.
(3)the pattern of nonzero values in the shape drawn with the smooth brush looks like:

```
>>> obj_6            #Not quite right but it's similar to this structure
array([[  0,   0,   1,   1,   1,   1,   0,   0],  
       [  0,   1,   6,  12,  15,   9,   3,   0],  
       [  0,   7,  24,  50,  57,  35,  12,   1],  
       [  2,  14,  52, 105, 119,  74,  24,   3],
       [  2,  16,  60, 122, 139,  86,  29,   4],
       [  1,  10,  37,  77,  88,  54,  18,   3],
       [  0,   3,  12,  25,  29,  18,   5,   1],
       [  0,   0,   1,   4,   5,   3,   1,   0]], dtype=uint8)
```

(4) To get the whole picture :
one:
[image]
two:
[image]
Thanks for your patience.

Update(1):
To make clear ,I posted the two images and the the related results:

Comment: Thanks for adding `obj_6`.  Could you also post `second.jpg` somewhere?

Comment: You mean the jpg format of the second.png???

Comment: OK, the PNG file is there--thanks.  When I run `label(img)` on the file `twozg.png` using the default structure (the + structure), I get 6 features, because the brush shape has one pixel that is only connected to the rest via a single diagonal.  If I use the full 3x3 structure, I get 5 features.

Comment: Although I've already tried it with a structure(3x3) before posting but trying it now  I see it works ,so you are right after all lol.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does the pattern of nonzero values look like in the shape drawn with the smooth brush?  If there are many zeros in there, `label` will find many disconnected features.

For example, with this 4x4 block of pixels:

```
In [16]: img
Out[16]: 
array([[ 0. ,  0.5,  0. ,  1. ],
       [ 0. ,  0.5,  0.5,  0. ],
       [ 0.5,  0. ,  1. ,  0. ],
       [ 0.5,  0. ,  1. ,  0. ]])
```

`label(img)` finds three features:

```
In [17]: lbl, n = label(img)

In [18]: lbl
Out[18]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 2],
       [0, 1, 1, 0],
       [3, 0, 1, 0],
       [3, 0, 1, 0]])

In [19]: n
Out[19]: 3
```

I suspect this is what is happening in the pixels drawn with the smooth brush.

Comment: You have a point,but i don' think so for two reasons: (1)It gives the same result using a structure parameter inside `label`...(2) It could label the whole smooth brush shape

Comment: Mr.Warren you can put this structure as a parameter to see what I mean. s= generate_binary_structure(2,2)..`labl,n=label(img,s)`

Comment: Sure, for my example the full 3x3 structure results in one feature, but in general, it depends how sparse the zeros are in the shape drawn by the smooth brush.  Even the full 3x3 binary structure could result in multiple features if there are enough zeros in there.  Zoom in on a small section near the edge, and inspect the individual pixels.  That should help you determine if the nonzero pixels are dense enough to guarantee that the smooth brush shape is really a single feature.

Comment: Mr.Warren You may want to read my question again as I posted the actual images with its related results.

Answer (score 7):

To answer your question, the reason it labels an additional area is because you are using the default structure with a connectivity of one, and it doesn't know to look for a diagonal connection.

In addition to what Warren pointed out, where robust labeling is needed (that will treat diagonal pixels as connected), one can change this structure.  The default structure is as follows

```
In [32]: ndimage.morphology.generate_binary_structure(2, 1).astype("uint8")
Out[32]: 
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Which has a connectivity of 1.  This is extended to to whatever dimensional image you are working with.

If you want to use labeling without worrying about the small extras you get by default, you can change the call to ndimage.label by adding a "structure" keyword argument.  The structure (or kernel) is a binary object with the same rank as the image (dimensionality), and can be easily changed.  To create a full-rank

```
In [41]: struct=np.ones((3,3), dtype="bool8")

In [42]: struct
Out[42]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
In [43]: ndimage.label(img, structure=struct)
```

In theory, this should resolve the issue of adding small objects to the result.